# Cmake can't find QTCore, Win64, downloaded precompiled qt4.8.3

Tags: windows, qt, path, cmake

I have trouble making a software library work that depends on Qt < 5. The actual problem is that I cannot compile qt myself, because it will just never end (running for 5 days or so at 4 GB, I read somewhere that it should be 7GB at the end...)

Anyway, I got a precombiled qt version from someone and added the qt\bin path to my PATH variable(ya, I am on Win64).

When I now run the cmake script of the library I get the error "cannot find qtcore". I also tried to add the qt\include path to my PATH variable but that didn't do the job ):

Is there anything else that I miss?

cheers!

**SOLUTION:**

Okay,got it. I have to add the lib directory... (:.

2nd edit:

It seems like it is possible to copy the compiled qt folder to any location. Anyway I got it working in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately windows qt builds are not portable. You can move it to other computers but you need to place it to the exact path where it was compiled. And you need to copy all entire folder, not particular subfolders. Try to do this.

Comment: I had the complete folder copied (without all the temp files generated throughout the build process). It actually seems to work, but I am now getting an error that minimum req. qt is 4.5 not 4.8.4 (sorry, typo in the title) However, that is impossible since the library exiplicitly states that it does not support qt 4.5.x. I don't know if that is because I didn't use the exact path where the compiled qt version comes from.. but I will check this. thanks.